# Undefined symbols in a shared library compiled with a static library

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries, inclusion

I have a problem with linking together different libraries using it in one executable project.

Let's say Project A contains a function named `foo()`; It is compiled as a static library.
Project B contains a function named `bar()`, includes a header from A and compiled as a shared library with `-Wl`,`--whole-archive libA.a -Wl`,`--no-whole-archive flags`. 
libB.so was moved to `/usr/lib`.

Now, project C includes `B.h`, calls `bar()`, but wasn't compiled due to the reason of undefined reference to `foo()` function, which was defined in project A.

nm `libB.so` says:

```
U foo
```

I am using gcc, the programming language is C, the IDE is Eclipse CDT.

Is anyone who has an idea or tip to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: what does "nm <static lib>" says?

Comment: @Icarus3: It says T foo()

Comment: That's good. Now can you grab the gcc command line for building shared object? The reason I am asking because, I tried this at my end and "nm <shared object>" shows "T foo". So there has to be something weird going on while building the shared object.

Comment: @Icarus3 Here it is: gcc -Wl,--whole-archive /usr/lib/libA.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -shared -o "libB.so"  ./sys/sys_confs.o ...further object files... ./mpt_srvlib.o   -lssl -lm -lrt -lpthread

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to reproduce this at my end. Just for the information I am using gcc-4.8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Icarus3 for his contribution, the problem is restricted.

Some functions in ProjectA used restrict keyword, thus it was compiled with -std=gnu99. It turns out that eliminating this keyword from the code and the -std=gnu99 from the compiling command eventually solved the problem.